# MVC submit button is not responding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code which invokes a method called search once the search button is submitted. But the problem rely on that the submit button does not make call to the actionresult search in all cases:

Index page in where it has the form

```
<section class="search-sec">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search","Home",FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <input type="text" name="SearchTitle" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Job Title, Skills, Company!">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Location">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                                <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-danger wrn-btn">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string SearchTitle)
{
    var result = db.Job.Where(m => m.JobTitle.Contains(SearchTitle)).ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add [HttpPost] attribute like this on top of your action

it will fix your issue

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Search(string SearchTitle)
{
   var result = db.Job.Where(m => m.JobTitle.Contains(SearchTitle)).ToList();
   return View(result);
}
```

Comment: ok..but the code you have provided i'm not seeing anywhere the [HttpPost] attribute

Answer (score -1):

Moving the Beginform to the top will solve your problem rather than having it inside the row. this will solve the problem.

```
<section class="search-sec">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <input type="text" name="searchTitle" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Job Title, Skills, Company!">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Location">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-danger wrn-btn">Search</button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```